# Not able to acess Namenode web URL

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, port, namenode, hadoop-2.7.2

I tried accessing the web url of `namenode` with the `namenode IP`. It throwed an error `HTTP ERROR 404` `Problem accessing /dfshealth.jsp. Reason: NOT_FOUND`

I am able to access the `Namenode` web url with the hostname.

`/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

192.168.10.103  impc2390


192.168.10.102  impc2359

192.168.10.101  impc2391

192.168.10.111  impc2394

192.168.10.104  impc2361
```

I tried `192.168.10.104:50070`
It throwed an error that `page not found`

I tried with `impc2361:50070`
It worked fine

Why am I not able to access the page with Ip of the computer?

Comment: can you share full path in url when you do `impc2361:50070` and when you do `192.168.10.104:50070`?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I entered 192.168.10.104:50070 and impc2361:50070

Comment: Yes Paul I understood that. But when you enter those address and port and hit enter the url must append something else as well. I wanted to see the appended strings. for example when I do `http://dwnpcpu369:50070` in my url and hit enter the whole path becomes `http://dwnpcpu369:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview`.  Your error is `Problem accessing /dfshealth.jsp` and `jsp` files had been removed in new hadoop. I hope you got me

Comment: @RameshMaharjan  When I enter 192.168.10.104:50070 it shows   http://192.168.10.104:50070/dfshealth.jsp and when i enter impc2361:50070 it shows http://impc2361:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview

Comment: can't you get access to namenode when you do ` impc2361:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview`?

Comment: I get access to namenode when i enter impc2361:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview`

Comment: your problem is already solved then. As I already mentioned in my previous comment that dfshealth.jsp page has been removed in new hadoop so you won't get namenode on that page. `dfshealth.jsp` was used for older hadoop1

Comment: @RameshMaharjan , Okay I understood the problem but how come iam able to acess the same page with the hostname. Hostname indirectly uses the IP address to access the port number. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. May be that your browswer has cached that address. Try copy pasting `192.168.10.104:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview` in your browswer. I think you should be able to view the namenode  in web UI

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, It worked brother. Thanks a lot

Comment: I had already answered that in my previous comments that dfshealth.jsp is removed in newer versions of hadoop. I think I didn't sound clear so you got confused. :). Shall I answer this question then ? so that you can accept it and it will help others as well. :)

Comment: Okay. I coudnt understand in the first go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146595/discussion-between-basil-paul-and-ramesh-maharjan).

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind `HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /dfshealth.jsp. Reason: NOT_FOUND` error is because `Namenode` `web UI` is trying to access `dfshealth.jsp` page which has been removed in the latest `hadoop` releases.

When you enter `NamenodeIP` and port `50070` and hit enter, `dfshealth.jsp` must have been appended. May be you had older version of `hadoop` and your `broswer` had `cached` the address.

The solution to this would be either you clear the `browser cache` or append   `/dfshealth.html#tab-overview` as

```
192.168.10.104:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview
```

Hope to see your problem solved with this answer.